# Install Ubuntu, but still boot into Windows 7 (no GRUB screen)

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

First of all I want to boot Windows only, I'm not having a duel-boot problem

I want to install Ubuntu on my Laptop after Windows has really become slow and even the live CD boots faster, the main problem is that my parents use my laptop and they wouldn't know what to do at the GRUB screen. I know how to set up GRUB on my flash drive but I still have the problem that Ubuntu is likely to boot instead of Windows, any help?

If it helps, I am running Windows 7 32-bit and I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 as it seems that 14.04 live CD doesn't boot on my laptop, I only have one hard drive installed with 2 partitions (3 when I've installed Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup grub to boot into windows by default, with a 10 second time-out.  The you can choose Ubuntu, but if your parents just wait out the 10 seconds, it will boot into Windows.

A good editor for grub is grub-customizer, which you can et from a [launchpad ppa](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer)

After installation of Ubuntu, open a terminal window <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and enter the commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then you can open the dash, and type 'grub' which will locate the program for you.  You will need to change the general settings, so that the "default entry" points to the windows boot, and change the timeout to a desired amount of time.

[image]

Comment: I'll try the customiser after I install Ubuntu, hopefully it works

Comment: first try install `boot-repair` before `grub-customizer` and repair your Windows Boot Chain

Comment: My laptop seems to autoboot into Win 7 anyway, I'll just install GRUB onto my flash drive. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from your **Live CD** (choose **Try Ubuntu** option).
2. Open **Terminal**
3. Type: `sudo apt-get install boot-repair && boot-repair` press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Repair your **GRUB** with **Recommended configuration**.
5. Reboot.
6. If **Windows** boot **>** your BIOS HDD chain is WRONG. Try to change order to boot from right MBR.
7. Though (!) after `boot-repair` you should to have right MBR at all HDD and maybe you will need a little fix Windows chainloader, but from Ubuntu already.

That's all.

Comment: I want it to boot to windows, I can get GRUB onto a flash drive and select it when my laptop boots

Comment: this is the way really indifferently where you want to have your GRUB, but if your Windows7 boot without "pit-stop" the suggest for customizer just absurdly stupid. Where you want to install customizer? Under the Windows or it is a joking trolling? And if you do not have dual-boot bugs too .. )) Really bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

I had a somehow similar problem. After installing ubuntu side-by-side with windows 8, it always booted straight into windows.

My solution: Even though I installed ubuntu with bios-boot-setting UEFI, I can now boot ubuntu by setting bios-boot-setting back to legacy. For booting windows I set it to UEFI.

Of course, entering the bios  each time I want to boot the other OS is a bit unlovely, but at least it is workng this way.